# Proving $\exists x\lnot R(x), \forall x(P(x)\to Q(x)), \forall x(\lnot Q(x) \lor R(x)) \vdash \exists x\lnot P(x)$

Tags: logic, solution-verification, natural-deduction

This is the proof we have to prove:
$$\exists x\lnot R(x), \forall x(P(x)\to Q(x)), \forall x(\lnot Q(x) \lor R(x)) \vdash \exists x\lnot P(x)$$

My proof:

1. $∀x(P(x)→Q(x))$ From data
2. $∃x¬R(x)$ From data
3. $∀x(¬Q(x) ∨ R(x))$ From data
4. $¬R(a)$ 2. and ∃-E
5. $P(a)→Q(a)$ 1. and ∀-E
6. $¬Q(a) ∨ R(a)$ 3. and ∀-E
7. $¬Q(a)$ 4., 6., and vE2.
8. $P(a)→¬Q(a)$ 5., 8., and ¬I
9. $¬P(a)$ From sub computation box
10. $∃x¬P(x)$ 9. and ∃-I

Is my proof correct? I am unsure about line 8. in particular

These are the rules we use:

Comment: The proof looks right, but I'm totally lost on what "sub computation box" means

Comment: I see a bunch of propositional logic rules in the link, but no rules involving quantifiers.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: They are the same for quantifiers @Bram28

Comment: The rules for quantifiers are different from those involving the truth-functional operators. How do you eliminate or introduce universals or existentials?  I also don;t understand what is happening on line 8 (which, by the way, refers to itself ..)

Comment: @jasmineoverflow  You are using an old version of the natural deduction rules, so they are somewhat unfamiliar.  Please check how 'existential elimination' is implemented in your system - it looks like '*existential instantiation*' then '*existential generalisation*' .

Answer (score 1):

> My proof:

The rules are an older version of natural deduction, so are a bit unfamiliar.  But it looks mostly okay.

> $~$ 1. $∀x(P(x)→Q(x))$ From data
>
> $~$ 2. $∃x¬R(x)$ From data
>
> $~$ 3. $∀x(¬Q(x) ∨ R(x))$ From data
>
> $~$ 4. $¬R(a)$ 2. and ∃-E

That is not typically how existential elimination is used, but I have seen it so in older text, so maybe yours does.  Please check your reference.

> $~$ 5. $P(a)→Q(a)$ 1. and ∀-E
>
> $\quad$ 6. $¬Q(a) ∨ R(a)$ 3. and ∀-E
>
> $\quad$ 7. $¬Q(a)$ 4., 6., and vE2.
>
> $~$ 8. $P(a)→¬Q(a)$ 5., 8., and ¬I

This should be derived using $\to\mathsf I$ .  So raise a 'sub computation box' with the assumption of $P(a)$ just before line 6 .

> $~$ 9. $¬P(a)$ From sub computation box

Now, *this* is where $\lnot\mathsf I$ is used, calling $5$ and $8$.

> $~$ 10. $∃x¬P(x)$ 9. and ∃-I

---

$$\boxed{\begin{array}{l}~~1.~~\forall x~(P(x)\to Q(x))\\~~2.~~\exists x~\lnot R(x)\\~~3.~~\forall x~(\lnot Q(x)\vee R(x)\\\hline{~~4.~~\lnot R(a)\hspace{20ex}2, \exists{-}\mathsf E\\~~5.~~P(a)\to Q(a)\hspace{13ex} 1, \forall{-}\mathsf E\\\quad\boxed{\begin{array}{l}5.1.~~P(a)\\\hline{~~6.~~\lnot Q(a)\vee R(a)\hspace{9ex} 3, \forall{-}\mathsf E\\~~7.~~\lnot Q(a)\hspace{16ex} 4, 6,\vee{-}\mathsf E2}\end{array}}\\~~8.~~P(a)\to\lnot Q(a)\hspace{11ex}5a{-}7,{\to}{-}\mathsf I\\~~9.~~\lnot P(a)\hspace{20ex} 5, 8, \lnot{-}\mathsf I\\10.~~\exists x~\lnot P(x)\hspace{17ex} 9, \exists{-}\mathsf I}\end{array}}$$

Answer (score 0):

Your step 8 has to be wrong because it depends on itself.  Try applying rule $\rightarrow$I2 to rule 7 instead.  Then there will be a negation rule that applies to 5 and 8 (there is no computation box).